# Can a problem with clutch hydraulics cause car not to steer straight?

Tags: clutch-hydraulics

For example if you have leaks or air I imagine the gears won’t engage properly.

Could this lead to lower transmission and engine performance which In turn leads to car not feeling straight, maybe feeling heavy on one side?

I imagine it can because I experienced such a thing due to old oil then changing the oil made car run smooth again etc.

Also with a recent clutch fluid bleed car improved in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

To my mind, there is no way clutch hydraulics will have anything to do with the steering of the vehicle. These two systems do not connect or influence the other in any way, shape, or form. There has to be something else going on.